# jQuery で animate させているのに HTML に変化がない

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {

  var duration = 300;

  $('#buttons1 button:nth-child(-n+4)')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#ae5e9b',
        color: '#fff'
      }, duration);


    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#ebc000'
      }, duration);


    });
});
```

HTML に変化がありません。文法的におかしいところはありますか。

Answer (score 1):

[Animation Properties and Values](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)によると、`.anitamte()`は[JQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) pluginを使わないと、`background-color`をアニメーション化できないと記載されています。

以下のように、[JQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) pluginを使う必要があります。

```js
$(function() {

  var duration = 300;

  $('#buttons1 button:nth-child(-n+4)')
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: $.Color('#ae5e9b'),
        color: $.Color('#fff')
      }, duration);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: $.Color('#fff'),
        color: $.Color('#ebc000')
      }, duration);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons1">
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
  <button>button4</button>
  <button>button5</button>
  <button>button6</button>
</div>
```